# zend date validation error

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I am using a Zend form for my web site. There is a date field present for dob.

```
 $date_of_birth      = $this->createElement('text','date_of_birth')
                        -> setAttrib('class','txt_feeld')
                        -> setAttrib('placeholder', 'dd-mm-yyyy')
                        -> setRequired(true);   
    $date_of_birth      -> addValidator('NotEmpty', true)
                        -> getValidator('NotEmpty')->setMessage('Enter date of birth');
    $date_of_birth      -> addValidator('date',true, array('dd-mm-yyyy'))
                        -> getValidator('date')->setMessage('Invalid Date');
    $date_of_birth      -> setDecorators(array('ViewHelper','Errors'));
```

After enter this date format 'dd-mm-yy' i want to generate a error message. Because i validate the date like this format  dd-mm-yyyy. But i can't getting error message.

if anything wrong in this code. please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Have try like this way. this is working from my end.

```
$f = new Zend_Form();
$f->addElement('text', 'date_of_birth', array(
    'required'   => false,
    'validators'  => array (
       array('date', false, array('MM/dd/yyyy'))
    ),
    'label'      => 'Date of Birth:',
    'class'      => 'form-date'
));

$data = array(
    'projected-start' => '13/03/2011'
);
var_dump( $f->isValid( $data ) );
var_dump( $f->getErrors() );
die;
```

Please let me know if i can help you more

Comment: My basic requirement is to adopt this 'dd-mm-yyyy' format. The only problem in my code is 'Year' format. When i enter a year 13 it must become an error and the must enter the year 2013. Thanks for your reply